# Selenium AssertText

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, assertion

I want to assert that a string of text is present on a page before moving on and am having trouble.

I am using Selenium `Webdriver` with `Java`.  Here is the code I've tried:

```
String str2 = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00$MainContent$cklRepair$10")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue(str2.contains("text"), "Lubrication");
```

and

```
boolean textFound = true;
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_cklRepair_10"));
    textFound = true;
}catch (Exception e) {
    textFound = false;
}
```

I want to validate that *Lubrication* exists.

HTML:

```
 <span class="label"> 
    <input id="ctl00_MainContent_cklRepair_10" type="checkbox" value="Lubrication,600" onclick "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$cklRepair$10\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$MainContent$cklRepair$10"> 
        <label for="ctl00_MainContent_cklRepair_10">Lubrication</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str2` already returns the string to compare with whereas `contains()` does a search if the `str2` contains the `Lubrication` text.

```
Assert.assertTrue(str2.contains("Lubrication"));
```

And, just looked at the selector and looks the selector you are using is not returning the text. You can use the following `xpath` instead

```
//input[contains(@id,'MainContent_cklRepair')]//..//label
```

The complete code block should look like:

```
By byXpath = By.xpath)("//input[contains(@id,'MainContent_cklRepair')]//..//label");
String str2 = driver.findElement(byXpath).getText();
Assert.assertTrue(str2.contains("Lubrication"));
```